# Cummulative Dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, sum, cumulative-sum

I am trying to write a python function where for each key (the dates), the value would be the sum of that day's result and the previous day(s) (sort of following the same logic as the fibonacci sequence).

For example, I have:

`{20200516: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200517: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200518: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200519: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}}`

but I want to have:

`{20200516: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200517: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200518: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200519: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 2, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 2}`

What I have done until now:

```
def summing(d):
    '''
    each key after the first one is the sum of the one before and its own result
    
    
    >>> {20200516: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200517: {'Level1': 0, 
        'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200518: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 
        0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200519: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}}
    
    {20200516: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200517: {'Level1': 0, 
    'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200518: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, ' 
    Level4': 1}, 20200519: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 2, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 2}
    '''
    #STILL IN PROGRESS
    c={}
    for key in d:
        if key == 20200516:
            c[20200516]=d[20200516]
        else:
            c[key]=d[key-1]+d[key]
    
    return c
```

Comment: Be aware that your keys are not necessarily sorted by date (order they were created in python3) although you can use sorted(d.keys()) Are you intending to use the string or number for the date? You cannot just add and subtract numbers to the date-like-number. You'll want to use an actual date object to count days, and use datetime.timedelta to add/subtract a day.

Comment: I have already modified the date provided by the datetime library to be of type integer.

Comment: I'll elaborate. What day comes after 20200531? Currently you're adding 1, so you will be expecting 20200532

Comment: @KennyOstrom Oh, I forgot about that aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a good effort, but you can't just add dicts like that. Here's a minimal change to get from your input to desired output, by using dict comprehension to add the value for each entry in the daily record:

```
from pprint import pprint

def summing_oneday(d1, d2):
    return {key: d1[key] + d2[key] for key in d2}

def summing(data):
    result = {}
    for day in sorted(data.keys()):
        if not result:
            result[day] = data[day]
        else:
            result[day] = summing_oneday(previous, data[day])
        previous = result[day]
    return result
    
data = {20200516: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200517: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}, 20200518: {'Level1': 1, 'Level2': 0, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 0}, 20200519: {'Level1': 0, 'Level2': 1, 'Level3': 0, 'Level4': 1}}
pprint(summing(data))
```

I'm assuming all the keys are present on all the daily records. Otherwise we'll have to deal with that.